# Make SQL Server 2005 accessible via Internet

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an application that runs on a client's server built on a SQL Server 2005 database.

We have now developed an ASP.NET v2 application which connects to this database.  This web application will be hosted on an ISP's server but needs to access the SQL Server database on the client's server.

The client's server has a firewall and so forth so I assume it should be possible to make the SQL Server accessible via the Internet but of course I am woriied about security.  Can someone point me to some best practices to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you develop a web service to run on the client's server? you probably want to avoid opening SQL Server to the world.

Comment: It looks like this is the optimal solution going foward - it requires somewhat of a re-write of the web application as this currently connects directly to the SQL Server.  As a short term solution we are considering replicating data to a SQL Server on the web server.

Answer (score 4):

Best practice: DO NOT DO IT. Lets leave security concerns aside - the ip delay will significantly slow you down. Try it out first, but the large ping times MAY be terrible for you.

THat said, all you noramlly have to do (not assuming reconfiguration) is to allow:
* The server somehow to be reached
* On Port 1433 (default port).

Use A VPN or IPSEC to secure traffic and make sure that "accessible through the internet" is not "accessible for every idiot out there". The ISP admin should be able to help you, or the customers admins. But I would not do it - the performance may not be to your liking. Test performance out first.

Comment: Ok - it looks like opening up the SQL Server is not a long term solution so will look at accessing the required data via web services.